# Scipy fft backends possibilities

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I am looking for documentation about the fft backends. It is very short. But
I found this in a RalfGommers slide share: 
[image]

My question here is, what other backends can be tested? According to docs,
PyFFTW provides a way to replace a number of functions in `scipy.fft` with its own functions, which are usually significantly faster, via `pyfftw.interfaces`. Because PyFFTW relies on the GPL-licensed FFTW it cannot be included in SciPy. Users for whom the speed of FFT routines is critical should consider installing PyFFTW.

So following release notes and GitHub SciPy and NumPy issues, you both have adopted pocketfft by default.
With backend I can use fftw with its licenses limitations.
But what else can I do with that backend properties? I really don't understand which strings I can use, or which are the kind of objects that are commented here:

> Parameters
>
> ```
> backend: {object, ‘scipy’}
>
>     The backend to use. Can either be a str containing the name of a known backend {‘scipy’}, or an object that implements the uarray protocol.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything in the docs except what you already know. But i took a look at _backends.py in the scipy.fft module:

```
_named_backends = {
    'scipy': _ScipyBackend,
}

def _backend_from_arg(backend):
    """Maps strings to known backends and validates the backend"""

    if isinstance(backend, str):
        try:
            backend = _named_backends[backend]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError('Unknown backend {}'.format(backend))

    if backend.__ua_domain__ != 'numpy.scipy.fft':
        raise ValueError('Backend does not implement "numpy.scipy.fft"')

    return backend
```

It seems my installation only accepts 'scipy'.